# Change the css based on select value item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q362U/)

i have a jquery which is for that, if the selected value is "<>"(Between) i want to change the style to display:block to an input box .. but  here all the selected items css is changed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.condition-change').change(function () {
        if ($('select[name="SearchCondition"]').find('option[value="<>"]').attr("selected", true)) {
            $('.second-value').css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong condition

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.condition-change').change(function () {
    if($('select[name="SearchCondition"]').find('option[value="<>"]').prop("selected")==true)
    {
        $('.second-value').css("display", "block");
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('.condition-change').change(function () {
    if($(this).val().trim() === '<>') {
        $('.second-value').show();
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q362U/3/)

Or

```
$('.condition-change').change(function () {
    $('.second-value').toggle($(this).val().trim() === '<>');
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/q362U/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to access the selected option value which you can get using val(), so put condition on val(),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q362U/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.condition-change').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "<>") {
            $('.second-value').css("display", "block");
        }
    });
});
```

Also using show and hide instead of setting css.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q362U/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.condition-change').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "<>") 
            $('.second-value').show();
        else
            $('.second-value').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// add .is(":checked") function to check whether "<>" value option  is selected

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.condition-change').change(function () {
            if($('select[name="SearchCondition"]').find('option[value="<>"]').is(":checked"))
            {
                $('.second-value').css("display", "block");
            }
            else
            {
                $('.second-value').css("display", "none");
            }

        });

      });
```